# Use an IF statement within a VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I would like to use an IF statement within an existing VLOOKUP formula in the below example:

[image]

In column P there is an existing formula:

```
=ROUND(VLOOKUP([@USER]; Voice_NPS_FCR[[user_retea]:[AHT]]; 7; FALSE)*(1-[@Adjustment]);2)
```

and I would like to wrap an IF statement around it which checks the value of column Q. If the value is not equal (<>) to the string "TARGET" then it should use the value of column O (in P). If the value is equal to the to the string "TARGET" it should do nothing else, then the existing formula.

I tried something like:

```
=IF(ISTEXT([AHT Performance];"TARGET"(ROUND(VLOOKUP([@USER]; Voice_NPS_FCR[[user_retea]:[AHT]]; 7; FALSE)*(1-[@Adjustment]);2)), "", [Column3])
```

But that didn't work unfortunately. Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: Try: `IF([AHT Performance]="TARGET";[Column3];ROUND(VLOOKUP([@USER]; Voice_NPS_FCR[[user_retea]:[AHT]]; 7; FALSE)*(1-[@Adjustment]);2))`

Comment: or, `=IF([AHT Performance]<>"TARGET";ROUND(VLOOKUP([@USER]; Voice_NPS_FCR[[user_retea]:[AHT]]; 7; FALSE)*(1-[@Adjustment]);2);[Column3])`

Comment: You don't need `ISTEXT()` function here, since it checks whether the values are `TEXT` or `Non Text` and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`'s. Simply use the Boolean logic to check whether the adjacent cell is `TARGET` or not. **[ISTEXT()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/is-functions-0f2d7971-6019-40a0-a171-f2d869135665)**

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya, thank you for the formula's and explanation. Unfortunately I received a "circular reference" notification for both formula's. Any idea how I can solve that?

Comment: Ah, yes it could be because you are using the range or cell reference `[AHT]`, within the same formula where the formulas are placed

Comment: can you advise a workaround for this?

Comment: does the table array within the same worksheet you are referring the formula with? you can enable the iterative calculations to avoid circular reference but its not suggested

Comment: yes the array is in the same worksheet

Comment: If you need it specifically then you can enable in the `Calculation options` section, select the `Enable iterative` calculation check box. [Change formula recalculation, iteration, or precision in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-formula-recalculation-iteration-or-precision-in-excel-73fc7dac-91cf-4d36-86e8-67124f6bcce4)

Comment: Unfortunately that gives an #SPILL error....

Comment: it gives `#SPILL` error because we have selected the whole range instead of checking the cell, so that said the formula needs to be `=IF(Voice_NPS_FCR[@[AHT Performance]]<>"TARGET";ROUND(VLOOKUP([@USER]; Voice_NPS_FCR[[user_retea]:[AHT]]; 7; FALSE)*(1-[@Adjustment]);2);Voice_NPS_FCR[@[Column3]])`

Comment: or, `=IF(Voice_NPS_FCR[@[AHT Performance]]="TARGET";Voice_NPS_FCR[@[Column3]];ROUND(VLOOKUP([@USER]; Voice_NPS_FCR[[user_retea]:[AHT]]; 7; FALSE)*(1-[@Adjustment]);2))`

Comment: no, unfortunately not, de formula throws a formula error....

Comment: Try evaluating and see where it gives the error, is it because of this, just noticed this one, `(1-[@Adjustment]);2)` here is a syntax error because of the last part `;2`

Comment: yes, you're right, its the round bracket right after `2)` and the round bracket in front of `(VLOOKUP`

Comment: no, I couldn't solve it :(